# Clear date in flatpickr change event

Tags: javascript, flatpickr

I have several flatpickr inputs on a page, they all have class='flatpickr'.  I want to call the clear method when a user manually deletes the date form the input. What's the syntax to access the the actual flatpickr instance using the following event handler?

```
<input id="OpenDate" name="OpenDate" type="text" v-model="Item.OpenDate" class="form-control form-control-sm flatpickr"  />

$('.flatpickr').change(function () {
  console.log(this); // html input control
  console.log($(this)); // jquery object instance
  // flatpickr instance ???
  // if (value == '')
  //   ???.clear();
});
```

Comment: Does `this._flatpickr` works?

Comment: No.  It did do something though.  The exception it threw was: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.  What's the underscore prefix for?

Comment: It's the instance `if( !this.value || !this.value.length ) {this._flatpickr.clear();}`

Comment: 2flatpickr:2 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.
    at ge (flatpickr:2)
    at Object.h.clear (flatpickr:2)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (site.js?v=kFxD6TLKk3MDNE9solaKgb89_u7WIbrlz3IvNbGfD1k:23)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery.js:5183)
    at HTMLInputElement.elemData.handle (jquery.js:4991)
    at ge (flatpickr:2)
    at Object.h.clear (flatpickr:2)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (site.js?v=kFxD6TLKk3MDNE9solaKgb89_u7WIbrlz3IvNbGfD1k:23)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery.js:5183)
    at HTMLInputElement.elemData.handle (jquery.js:4991

Comment: Very interesting.. Checking

Comment: Maybe this? https://jsfiddle.net/03eus5c7/2/

Comment: Thanks for your effort, you helped me understand the logic flaw in my design.  Calling the clear method within the change event infinitely triggers a new change event which overflows the stack:(  I do NOT want to have an extraneous button just to clear the internal date, it disturbs my UI.

Comment: I know, it was just for the demo, but the input element is readonly anyways so how does the user clears the input? I checked and if you simply click on the backspace the input clears and so is the instance

Comment: I'm using this for the options: { dateFormat: "M d, Y", allowInput: true }.  It feels crippling to not allow user edits.

Comment: Oh, I see. Checking

Comment: Something like this then? https://jsfiddle.net/4hsrft0k/

Comment: Oh wait... It's not working properly

Comment: I think I got it now: https://jsfiddle.net/1tvwLfh4/

Comment: Wow, it definitely works.  Certainly not a fan of how involved it is.  Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, it's a problem with how the plugin works and I'm not very proud of this workaround, but it is what it is :)

Comment: How do I credit you with the answer?  I'm new here, not certain on user protocols yet.

Comment: Let me post an answer - One second...

Comment: I posted an answer, And I was able to make my original code much more simple - (You can click on the green `✔` icon to accept it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that when you call the `flatpickr.clear()` function from within a `change` event, it cause an infinite loop (Because the `clear` function calls the `change` event too).

My workaround was to use a flag `shouldClear` and set it on the the element  that needs to be cleared:

```js
flatpickr(".flatpickr",{dateFormat: "M d, Y", allowInput: true });

$(".flatpickr").on('input', function(e) {
    if(!this.shouldClear && !this.value.length && this._flatpickr.currentYear ) {
   this.shouldClear = true;
   this._flatpickr.clear();
   this.shouldClear = false;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr"></script>

<input id="OpenDate1" name="OpenDate" type="text"  class="form-control form-control-sm flatpickr"  autocomplete="off" />
<input id="OpenDate2" name="OpenDate" type="text"  class="form-control form-control-sm flatpickr"  />
<input id="OpenDate3" name="OpenDate" type="text"  class="form-control form-control-sm flatpickr"  />
```